# How to attach an xml file to php variable

Tags: php, xml

i have been created an xml file and named it 'input.xml'. When i'm trying to add a file (attach to string) in php, i get 500 browser error.

---

This is how i importing my xml to variable (working way):

```
 $xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>Movie 1</title>
 </movie>

  <movie>
  <title>Movie 2</title>
 </movie>

 <categories>
  <category>
    <name>Example category</name>
  </category>
 </categories>
</movies>
XML;
```

---

This is how i want to import my xml (from input.xml file) (not working way):

```
 $xmlstr = simplexml_load_file("input.xml");
```

---

This is how my php code looks like:

```
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($movies->movie as $mov) {
   echo "We found a movie!<br>";
}

foreach ($movies->categories as $cat) {
    echo "We found a category!<br>";
}
```

---

And this is my input.xml file content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>Movie 1</title>
 </movie>

  <movie>
  <title>Movie 2</title>
 </movie>

 <categories>
  <category>
    <name>Example category</name>
  </category>
 </categories>
</movies>
```

Comment: What error are you getting in your log?

Comment: try `$movies = simplexml_load_file("input.xml");` as `simplexml_load_file` returns an `SimpleXMLElement` Object

Comment: Hello @gview, Im getting this error:
`Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in ..../zil/index.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 ....}/zil/index.php(21): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in ..../zil/index.php on line 21\n`

My 21 line:
`$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);`

Comment: If you don't pass `true` as the third argument (data_is_url) in the constructor for `new SimpleXMLElement()`, it will use the first argument as XML-data, not as a path. So you must do: `new SimpleXMLElement('input.xml', 0, true)`. You should always refer to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) if you can't get a PHP function/object working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

`simplexml_load_file` already returns a `SimpleXMLElement` for you. So, there's no need to use

```
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

Just:

```
$movies = simplexml_load_file("input.xml");

foreach ($movies->movie as $mov) {
   echo "We found a movie!<br>";
}

foreach ($movies->categories as $cat) {
    echo "We found a category!<br>";
}
```

Comment: Feel free to __accept__ an answer if it helps. Also if your other questions have a solution - accept ot/them too.